# How to remove the decorate colors characters in bash output?

Tags: bash, sed, colors, tr

A console program (translate-shell) has an output with colors and uses special decorate characters for this: ^[[22m, ^[[24m, ^[[1m... and so on.

I'd like to remove them to get a plain text.

I tried with tr -d "^[[22m" and with sed 's/[\^[[22m]//g', but only is removed the number, not the special character ^[

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You have multiple options:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output
- http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed
- and as `-no-ansi` as pointed out by Jens in other answer

**EDIT**

The [solution from commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed) does the job pretty well:

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
```

The [solution from unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output) might be better but is much longer and so you would want to create a separate script file because it is so long instead of just doing a shell one-liner.

Comment: The option in commandlinefu works perfectly, thanks: sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"

Comment: This is a link-only answer; please provide the relevant details in the answer itself.

Comment: the `'s/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m//g'` regex [works better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32167243/614800)

Answer (score 2):

I found this in [the manual](https://www.soimort.org/translate-shell/#usage) about the use of ANSI escape codes:

```
-no-ansi
    Do not use ANSI escape codes.
```

So you should add this option when starting the program.

Comment: No, that option remove other characters too (á é í ó ú ñ...)

Comment: @GeaPlanet Then you are doing something wrong. Those characters are NOT ansi escapes and should not be effected by `-no-ansi`. This sounds more like a configuration problem to me (or a bug in translate-shell).