# replace or delete character '#' in string with bash shell

Tags: bash

I have a string

> betree teks#[22m

and I want delete `#[22m`

. I use bash shell, is that possible?

Comment: If you want to replace: `str="betree teks#[22m"
repl="some string"
str=${str/#[22m/repl}`

Comment: you could use awk assuming the file test contains your string this will print only the part before the #: cat test | awk -F '#' '{ print $1 }'

Comment: thank all, I find this answer my qs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166976/how-to-remove-the-decorate-colors-characters-in-bash-output