# Python-Retrieve specific text from a string text

Tags: python, regex

I need to retrieve the string having a fixed start and end pattern from the original string:

**Original String:** `(0, '\x1b[0;36mlocal\x1b[0;0m:\n\x1b[0;32mdbsvr-234-00ty.triu.ty.test.com\x1b[0;0m', [])`

**Desired String:** `dbsvr-234-00ty.triu.ty.test.com`

Tried using the replace & split method but it did not give the accurate output I am looking for. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: You should first find a library dedicated for removing ANSI colors and run it over your text. (Like https://github.com/chalk/strip-ansi-cli but for Python) After that, do regular text processing.

Comment: There are quite a few Regex examples available, e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166976/how-to-remove-the-decorate-colors-characters-in-bash-output

Answer (score 1):

The `\x1b[0;36m` part contains ANSI chars. You need to clean them first. You can remove it by a library (as @Thomas Weller suggested) or you can simply use a regex to clean the string. The following code removes the ANSI chars from the given original string.

```
import re

ANSI_ESCAPE_REGEX = re.compile(r'\x1B\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')

original_string = """(0, '\x1b[0;36mlocal\x1b[0;0m:\n\x1b[0;32mdbsvr-234-00ty.triu.ty.test.com\x1b[0;0m', [])"""

# Clean color codes(ANSI Chars) from the string
clean_string = ANSI_ESCAPE_REGEX.sub('',original_string)
# (0, 'local:\ndbsvr-234-00ty.triu.ty.test.com', [])
```

After that, you can use regex again to find the desired string:

```
# Try to match desiderd string
TARGET_REGEX = re.compile('.*\\n([-\.\w]*).*')
result = TARGET_REGEX.match(clean_string)
desired_str = result.group(1)
# dbsvr-234-00ty.triu.ty.test.com
```

I hope this will be helpful.